# Discard some class values in a loop - avoiding a second element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am looping through a date picker, but do not want all values returned.

if "is-disabled" is in the class i don't want to select it.

Here is the loop i am currently using.

```
   List<WebElement> days = driver.findElements(By.className("c-datepicker-calendar__day"));    
       for(int i1=0; i1<days.size(); i1++) {
           System.out.println(days.get(i1).getText());
       }
```

Don't Want These :

```
<a class="c-datepicker-calendar__day is-disabled ng-binding ng-scope" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-repeat="px in prevMonthDays" style="">31</a>
```

Want these :

```
<a class="c-datepicker-calendar__day ng-binding ng-scope" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-repeat="px in prevMonthDays" style="">31</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it by using only one line. No need to check using if condition.

```
List<WebElement> days = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".c-datepicker-calendar__day:not(.is-disabled)"));
```

Try and see if you can use this selector to only select the on without .is-disabled

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below code snap:

```
List<WebElement> days = driver.findElements(By.className("c-datepicker-calendar__day"));   
for (WebElement elem : days) {
    String fullClassString = elem.getAttribute("class");            
    if(!fullClassString.contains("is-disabled")) {
        System.out.println(elem.getText());
    }   
}
```

Comment: @MarkH Hey bro! Can you please tell me what the problem of my answer is? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stream and filter it.

```
List<WebElement> filteredDays = days.stream()
    .filter(day -> !day.getAttribute("class").contains("is-disabled"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```